# How to break a joint in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

The task is to make a bicycle. When a stone is thrown to the bicycle, the bicycle should be scattered in different parts.

I've made the bicycle with bicycle frame and wheels and join them using Wheel Joint. I need to know how can I break these joints using Script or anything?

Please help...

Answer (score 2):

You can set **Joint.breakForce** to a value and then apply a force greater then this force to break it. if **Joint.breakForce = Mathf.Infinity** it will make joint unbreakable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. So, I am sharing that may help others.

I disabled the component of WheelJoint in script by using this line of code.

**GetComponent<"WheelJoint2D"> ().enabled = false;**//This line will disable the component. 
If you want to enable it use this.
**GetComponentInChildren<"WheelJoint2D"> ().enabled = true;**

*Use the name of Component without Quotes("") .